# JavaScript: getElementById does not return the width of a button

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

Why does the alert window not show the button's width here? I looked through similar questions, but it looks like my question is too simple to have an answer there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="jock" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() 
       {
       alert(document.getElementById("jock").style.width);
       }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The `style` object gives you only the styles that are explicitly associated with the element. Your `<button>` has no "style" attribute, so if no other code has added a "width" to the `style` object it won't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use offsetWidth instead of style width. This will get the elements true width value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <button id="jock" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert(document.getElementById("jock").offsetWidth);
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will. I am still waiting for the time limit to expire.

Answer (score 0):

There is no style attribute declared in the element. So `document.getElementById("jock").style.width` may not work,

But [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) can be used the get the width of the button in the window.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("jock")
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
  console.log(style.width)
}
```

```html
<button id="jock" onclick="myFunction()"> Try it
  </button>
```